# How to get only the logged in users details from firebase and populate an viewholder with only that information

Tags: java, android, firebase

I would like to know how to only populate this viewholder with the details of the current logged in user  getting the data from firebase. I have no idea where to start with this.

```
public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersViewHolder.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Users> UserList;

    public UsersViewHolder(Context context, List<Users> uList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.UserList = ulist;
    }

    @Override
    public UsersViewHolder.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).

       inflate(R.layout.activity_mydetails,parent,false);

        return new UsersViewHolder.ViewHolder(view ,context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Users users =UserList.get(position);


        holder.UserFirstName.setText(users.getUserfirstname());
        holder.UserSurname.setText(users.getUserlastname());
        holder.UserAddress.setText(users.getUseraddress());
        holder.UserPostcode.setText(users.getUserpostcode());
        holder.UserColourPreference.setText(users.getUsercolourpreference());
        holder.UserShoeSize.setText(users.getUsershoesize());
        holder.UserTopSize.setText(users.getUsertopsize());
        holder.UserWaistSize.setText(users.getUserwaistsize());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return UserList.size();//Returns all values
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView UserFirstName,UserSurname,UserAddress,UserPostcode,UserColourPreference,UserShoeSize,UserTopSize,UserWaistSize;

        String Userid;

        public  ViewHolder(View view,Context state){

            super (view);
            context =state;

            UserFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.FirstNameID);
            UserSurname =view.findViewById(R.id.SurnameID);
            UserAddress =view.findViewById(R.id.AddressID);
            UserPostcode=view.findViewById(R.id.PostcodeID);
            UserColourPreference=view.findViewById(R.id.ColourPreferenceSpinnerID);
            UserShoeSize=view.findViewById(R.id.ShoeSizeSpinnerID);
            UserTopSize=view.findViewById(R.id.TopSizeSpinnerID);
            UserWaistSize=view.findViewById(R.id.WaistSizeSpinnerID);

            Userid = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mydetails);

    FirebaseUserAuthentication = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUserLoggedIn= FirebaseUserAuthentication.getCurrentUser();
    UserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    UserDatabaseref = UserDatabase.getReference().child("Threads Users");
    UserDatabaseref.keepSynced(true);
    UserDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    PopulateListView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewOBJ);
    PopulateListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    PopulateListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    //PopulateListView.setReverseLayout(True);

}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    UserDatabaseref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Users details =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            UserDetails.add(details);
            Collections.reverse(UserDetails);
            Uviewholder = new UsersViewHolder(mydetails.this,UserDetails);
            PopulateListView.setAdapter(Uviewholder);
            Uviewholder.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: so you're already retrieving a list with all the users in your database?

Comment: yes,I just need to retrieve the current users data in that database

Comment: You'll need to save the userId as well, otherwise you won't be able to compare. Can we see where you retrieve the data from firebase?

Comment: Do you mean where I retrieve the users log in details ?

Comment: I mean where you fill the list that you pass to the adapter abov

Comment: i have added the adapter code above

Comment: is this not what you were asking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 UserDatabaseref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
     {
         @Override
         public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          Users details =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
        If(dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(FirebaseUserLoggedIn.getUid())){
                UserDetails.add(details);
       }
        Collections.reverse(UserDetails);
        Uviewholder = new UsersViewHolder(mydetails.this,UserDetails);
        PopulateListView.setAdapter(Uviewholder);
        Uviewholder.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

That way only when the Id of the retrieved user match with the logged in user it will added to the data source that will be passed to the view holder. Now your view holder will be able to show the info only about the logged in user.

Comment: hi levi i have another question,if i wanted to get the value stored in a node and compare that to the current user logged in how would i modify the above statement ?

Comment: It's pretty similar, you attach a addChildEventListener to the desired note and use the comparison just like the one above

Comment: in terms of the logic used would it be a child event listener within a child event listener if that makes sense ??

Comment: You want to compare the user data or the user id? If you want to compare the user data, then it's better to get the currently logged user data in a prior state then simply use it now. Nesting child events in my experience is complicated and not very efficient

Comment: so i want to do something slightly different to before ,I need to compare the current user logged in to a stored field within another key within firebase

Comment: the structure is User has user id ,user makes item ,item has its own id but also has a field  storing the user id

Comment: Okay, I'll point you to the direction and then if you have any questions you can ask. You should use queries https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries. You can build a query stating that you want to search in a certain nodes by a certain criteria, that being for example the currently logged user id :) Good luck

Comment: ok so my understanding is that this is what is required however i am getting an error message stating that the type must be boolean ?

Comment: it should be something like this  if(dataSnapshot.getKey()+ details.useridpurchaseditem).equals(FirebaseUserLoggedIn.getUid())

Comment: hi levi i still have not solved this ,can i ask what is wrong with my statement above